# load jquery function before content

Tags: javascript, jquery

i made this function:

```
var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

if (jq111("#tab-upsell_tab").find("div").length > 0){ 

} else {

    jq111(".upsell_tab_tab").hide();
    jq111("#tab-upsell_tab").hide();

}
```

This hide a element if are empty.

But on page load, `#tab-upsell_tab` appear for 1 second (if need to be hide) and i don't like it.

There is a way to load this function before this element? Or something similiar.

Edit: i accept a css solution, but how?

Comment: if you ran the js before content, it wouldn't do anything... you could hide it with css

Comment: reverse the logic and show it if it isn't empty

Comment: @smerny can you create an example please?

Comment: So why is there a delay? When are you calling the code above? Why are you doing it onload and not document ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `.upsell_tab_tab` and `#tab-upsell_tab` to `display: none` in your CSS. Change your JavaScript to this also:

```
var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

if (jq111("#tab-upsell_tab").find("div").length > 0){ 

  jq111(".upsell_tab_tab").show();
  jq111("#tab-upsell_tab").show();

}
```

This way your elements are hidden by default, and you must imperatively show them based on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`$.holdReady()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdReady) , [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready)

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var jq111 = jQuery.noConflict();

  jq111.holdReady(true);

  if (jq111("#tab-upsell_tab").find("div").length > 0) {

  } else {
    jq111(".upsell_tab_tab").hide();
    jq111("#tab-upsell_tab").hide();
  }

  jq111.holdReady(false);

  jq111(document).ready(function() {
    // do stuff
  })
})
```

`div` `.length` within `"#tab-upsell_tab"` not greater than `0`
http://plnkr.co/edit/Xp2RbPe65BaFeobtTVOL?p=preview

`div` `.length` within `"#tab-upsell_tab"` greater than `0`
http://plnkr.co/edit/ekSUelSinlM8baKQe74Y?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The DOM renders HTML, CSS, then JS. So if you want your HTML elements hidden then hide them with your CSS or you could create using a template system like mustache or in your JS code. I prefer creating them in your JS code. It makes your code cleaner and it lighter on the DOM.